Resizing VM disk under xcp-ng
I have a Debian VM running under xcp-ng. It has a single LVM volume that spans a single (VM) disk attached to the VM. I need to add some space to this LVM volume, so:

Shut down the VM
In Xen Orchestra changed VM disk size to its new size
Booted the VM
Checked lsblk output for the VM disk ... and it shows the original size ... ?!

This has gotta be something obvious. What am I missing?

is it your PV the entire disk? Have you check with fdisk if the size of the disk is the same?

In Xen Orchestra changed VM disk size to its new size It sounds like you didn't get this step right.

Figured it out. Freshly added space needs to be first made into a new partition (via fdisk/cfdisk). Then it will show up on lsblk. Then do pvcreate, vgextend, lvextend and resize2fs. Easy-peasy.

@Angstrom In that case lsblk didn't show the "original size" for the disk, but merely for the existing partition/PV on the disk...

@TomYan, well, yeah. Hindsight is 20/20.

lsblk typically shows both: a "new" size for a parent block device which is the disk, and the "old" size for the child block device, a partition/PV/whatever. That would helpful and really improve the question if you actually showed added the lsblk output with the said discrepancy, the answer could have pointed that directly by referring to that output.

lsblk shows partitions and the freshly added space is just space, not a partition. Once it's used to create one, then lsblk will show it.

lsblk shows all block devices, its lsblk, not ls"part" or whatever. It will show raw device sizes, partition sizes, PVs, LVs, software RAIDs, multipathed devices, caching; all of them, really.

@NikitaKipriyanov - You are correct. I am just blind and was looking at the size of existing partition in lsblk output rather than that of its host drive.

As per comments you did not extend the partition where VG is created. The procedure to extend is sample.

use cfdisk to extend the partition where is located VG
use command pvresize /dev/sda3 (replace sda3 with your partition!!!)
then check the size of VG: vgs
then extend the LV(s): lvextend -r -L +10GB /dev/mapper/rh-root (replace the desired size and path to VG device)

